# react-simple-keyboard using useEffect intial value of the state not able to set

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-simple-keyboard

Beginner here. Trying to get react-simple-keyboard working with React.

I am displaying the keyboard onfocus of the input just like this example
https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/editor/?d=hodgef/react-simple-keyboard-demos/tree/uc-showhide

but if I have some initial value for state called firstName and user should be able to update this value.
I am tryinh to set this value by keyboard.current.setInput using useEffect.
I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setInput' of undefined.

```
const {firstName} = input;
useEffect(() => {
  keyboard.current.setInput(firstName);
}, [firstName]);
```

thanks in advance!!

Comment: Is "keyboard" in your case an instance to the keyboardRef? Here's an example with this ref set up. https://hodgef.com/simple-keyboard/editor/?d=simple-keyboard/react-simple-keyboard-hooks-demo/tree/master You can also add an if statement around your setInput call to make sure keyboard.current is not undefined.